# use .env file in vscode when connected to Ubuntu server via ssh

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have created a workspace on my local machine to connect to Linux server. I connect to this server in VS Code using SSH extension as outlined in these docs. `https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_managing-extensions`.

When I run the `.py` application in my Local Workspace I get the error `UndefinedValueError: CREDENTIALS not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.`

The `.py` application is in the same directory as the `.env` file which houses the `CREDENTIALS` variable on the Linux server and when run on the Linux server works fine..

How do I tell vscode on my local machine to access the .env file when Im running the `.py` application locally?

```
from decouple import config

credentials = config('CREDENTIALS')
```

Only started working in this type of coding environment today so apologies in advance if I have missed something very simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the python-dotenv library, nice and easy. Install via
`pip install python-dotenv`

Then in your file call

`from dotenv import load_dotenv`
Then just call
`load_dotenv()`
And all your env variables declared in the file will be put into the environment table. As long as that `config` function is grabbing env variables it should work. If it doesn't, you could use

```py
Import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
EnvVar = os.getenv('CONFIG')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help using the above both ways I get `OSError: Starting path not found`.. Any ideas? Im assuming it cant find the .env

Comment: Got it , I specified the path to the .env from the linux server in `load_dotenv` that worked.. Thanks allot